# steam не загружается linux mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, steam

устанавливал steam из офф репозитория минт, после установки и запуска steam появляется как бы "прозрачное" окно авторизации, висит около 5 секунд и после этого отключается, скрин

[image: скриншот окна steam]

вот что выводит баш

```
Running Steam on linuxmint 19.3 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
/home/volik/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2020-04-09 16:06:51] Startup - updater built Apr  4 2020 00:37:13
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2020-04-09 16:06:51] Checking for update on startup
[2020-04-09 16:06:51] Проверка на наличие обновлений...
[2020-04-09 16:06:51] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2020-04-09 16:06:52] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1586022601, installed version 1586022601
[2020-04-09 16:06:52] Nothing to do
[2020-04-09 16:06:52] Проверка установки...
[2020-04-09 16:06:52] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2020-04-09 16:06:52] Verification complete
STEAM_RUNTIME_HEAVY: ./steam-runtime-heavy
```

подробности 
LinuxMint 19.3 (tricia)
ядро 5.3.0-46-generic (#38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:56 UTC 2020)
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz

Comment: Попробуйте скачать steam с их официального [сайта](https://store.steampowered.com/about/), возможно в офф.репозитории устаревшая версия.

Comment: Пробовал, результат тот же

Comment: Я не уверен, но возможно проблема в вашей графической оболочке, какую вы используете? И используете ли какие-нибудь темы, расширения для графического интерфейса и тому подобное?

Comment: Так же могу посоветовать попробовать установить другие драйвера видеокарты, из тех, что имеются в Менеджере драйверов

Comment: Cinnamon "из коробки" дополнительно никаких расширений не ставил

Comment: Вот, по поводу драйверов, менеджер их вообще не отображает для видюхи, у меня интегрированная intel iris plus graphic g1

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106512/discussion-between-junior98-and-h4cktivist).

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, проблема как раз в драйверах к вашей интегрированной видеокарте. Нашел небольшую инструкцию, по их установке на Linux:

> Если у вас на ноутбуке или компьютере используется видеокарта Intel, то вам необходимо перейти на [страницу загрузки драйвера](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads?keys=&download_type=11&download_version=All) и скачать установщик. Он будет в виде deb файла, который можно легко установить двойным кликом.

Можно так же установить драйверы следующими командами в терминале:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Теперь у появится вас самая последняя версия драйвера и просто перезагрузите компьютер.

[Источник](http://linuxmint.info/text/linux-mint-ustanovka-draivera.html)

Comment: Нет, не помогло